# Stripe Confirm Payment: payment_intent & payment_intent_client_secret are not set on my redirect url

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

This is [my checkout page URL](http://localhost:4200/#/marketplace/cart/checkout) where I enter the card detail.

`Onsubmit()` calls `stripe.confirmPayment()` with a redirect URL.
The redirect url to check the status is http://localhost:4200/#/marketplace/cart/status

[image: On submit function]

**ISSUE:**  **"payment_intent"** & **"payment_intent_client_secret"** are not properly set. The url params goes empty before redirection.

**Current:** http://localhost:4200/payment_intent="xxxxx"&payment_intent_client_secret="xxxxxx"

**Expected:** http://localhost:4200/#/marketplace/cart/status?payment_intent="xxxxx"&payment_intent_client_secret="xxxxxx"

I've followed the documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/bancontact/accept-a-payment & https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the value that `${window.location.origin}/${window.locations.hash}/?` resolves to? It seems like Stripe is redirecting to the URL that you give it, you code just may not be setting the URL that you are expecting.

Comment: ${window.location.origin}/${window.locations.hash} is perfectly set. I found out the problem. My angular app uses hashing strategy for routing. But, stripe doesn't seem to allow hashing in the route. It accepts default locationPath strategy.